# Unordered list within anchor tag Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to put anchor tag around an unordered list in rails. I can't find anything online. Is it not possible to do that in rails or is it very trivial and I am missing an obvious thing. I am not much familiar with the ruby-on-rails syntax because I am newbie in rails.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<article id="bookmark-list">
    <h1>Popular Bookmark List</h1>

    <div class="bookmark">
        <a href="../bookmarks/show.html">
            <ul>    
                <li>Article</li>
                <li>How did they find that monkey?</li>
                <li>&bigstar;&bigstar;&bigstar;&star;&star;</li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="bookmark">
        <a href="../bookmarks/show.html">
            <ul>    
                <li>Article</li>
                <li>How did they find that monkey?</li>
                <li>&bigstar;&bigstar;&bigstar;&star;&star;</li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ERB, then your *view* should look like this

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="bookmark">
  <a href="<%= item.link %>">
    <ul>
      <li><%= item.title %></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Notice @ionut-hulub comment, using `link_to` instead of pure anchor is better.

Comment: so for example in this case it would look like this: `<%= link_to(@item.link) do %> ...ul list.. <% end %>` ???

Comment: This depends on what do you want. `link_to` generates anchor linked to object path. Use `<a>` or custom helpers if you wish to link something statically or in some non-standard way. And yes, you're right with your sample.

Comment: It will be a list of links, so yeah your answer mixed with my sample will do the job for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
# => <a href="/profiles/1">
       <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
     </a>
```

[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)